# Where can I check which difficulty bracket I'm in?

Tags: dota-2

Supposedly DOTA 2 matchmaking is divided into brackets.

I want to know which difficulty bracket I'm in. How can I find this information?

Comment: By skill level, do you mean your level? If so, that's on the main menu. You can see other people's level by right-clicking on their name and looking at their Dota profile.

Comment: I mean the "bracket" or "priority" in which you are in. There are low / normal / high/ very high. I was bouncing between high / very high before they removed it and I want to know if I've advanced or not.

Comment: tldr: You can't.

Comment: There was a work around posted in reddit before.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best way to currently check your difficulty bracket:

1. Run Dota2 and open watch tab
2. Select Recent games
3. Press Filter button
4. Write your nickname
5. Select skill level (low, mid or high)

This way you can see which of your recent games have been in low, mid or high skill bracket.

Keep in mind that the high bracket still varies in skill greatly, so that might not be a a very accurate indication of your current ladder standing.

Comment: I don't think it's a very good idea, since Dota2 can't correctly guess match skill levels. Checking first few pages with very high skill level resulted in short (25min at most) boring matches. Meaning it was one sided to the extent that a team was averagely 5-6 levels higher than the other :(

Comment: also based on [this thread](http://www.playdota.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1125953) where they partially explained their MMR system those brackets has nothing to do with player's ratings.

Comment: For what's it worth, the difficulty bracket is the only way to track your progress at the moment (well there's the DotaBuffRating). And better players do end up in the higher brackets. But unfortunately a significant portion of Dota2 matches end up being one-sided.

Answer (score 8):

Valve has integrated a ranking system now

You can see your ranking after 1 match played in those categories (solo/team).

## <strike>Getting the information:</strike> (This no longer works)

After you have played 1 match you can open the ingame console and type the following:

`developer 1`

`dota_game_account_debug`

The console will give you all your profile information including:

Teamranking

`competitive_rank:`

and

`solo_competitive_rank:`

Furthermore there is information how stable your ranking is:

`competitive_rank_uncertainty:`

`solo_competitive_rank_uncertainty:`

Those get lower the more matches you play. It increases the accuracy of the rank.

## Comparing:

```
 5% 1100
10% 1500
25% 2000
50% 2250
75% 2731
90% 3200
95% 3900
99% 4100
```

This table is the official from http://blog.dota2.com/2013/12/matchmaking/

How to read: 95% means that you are better/have a better ranking then 95% of all other players. Basically it tells you that you are in the top 5% of all players.

*However, this table is based on normal matchmaking for now. Valve expects that this table will adjust with more data from ranking match* (thx for pointing that out decency)

Comment: Note that the table is specifically for what the rating distribution was like in normal matchmaking, and Valve expects ranked matchmaking to yield a different distribution.

Comment: When I posted this question there was no clear answer. Now, that valve have implemented the new MM system I feel that it should be closed. Thank you for your input.

Comment: Well. Valve just now disabled this way of getting your mmr before playing 10 matches.

Answer (score 4):

[According to sources](http://www.reddit.com/r/DotA2/comments/mqc55/checking_your_dota_2_beta_rankmmr/), the way to do it is:

> > To check your current "ranking" you must first enable the console (which you should either know how to do or know how to google). Then then launch game, open console and type these commands
> >
> > `developer 1`
> >
> > `dota_game_account_debug`
>
> i think that's the proper way to check your MMR atm. dont forget to disable developer after you check it, since the developer mode will make u see red text in-game

However, this has been patched out, apparently. Therefore it's no longer possible. :(

Follow up:

> Rank = mmr If you picked veteran, you start at 3000 MMR. It seems if
>   you picked something else you start lower. Rank uncertainty = some
>   kind of K factor used in determining your new MMR's after games.

Comment: Hi Simon, if you're quoting a source, would you mind linking the source so that people can read the whole article/thread if they wish, and we can give credit to the original author?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Dota 2 uses an MMR(Matchmaking Rating) system to match players. Each player is assigned a number to represent their skill level and players are matched to people with similar MMRs. While these were previously grouped into brackets for spectating, there are any real brackets in Dota 2.

Normally, your MMR is hidden, but in December 2013, Valve added a ranked mode. After reaching level 13, you can play Ranked Mode to get a separate, visible MMR after 10 calibration games. You can then view this MMR on your profile:
[image: My MMR on my profile, located on the right and under the Battle Points bar]

Currently, the average MMR is about 2250, with pro players around 5000, but this is likely to change somewhat.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Valve is iteratively taking out all of the possible ways people have used in the past to judge a person's skill. Currently I'm not aware of any ways and if there are any new ways discovered they will presumably be quickly removed, just as those in the past have been.

If and when Valve decides to add a public skill ranking system, you'll know.

Answer (score 0):

It's been removed to stop people being elitist over their "skill" level.

I think the only way to do it now is is through the Dota2 Web Api, you'll need some programming skills to do it.

You can also look at www.Pubstats.me - this will show you your % of games above the normal bracket, but you'll not be able to see the bracket of individual games.

Comment: The function is removed in the API, also since the last patch this website doesn't really work correctly.

Comment: Ah thanks. Tbh I'm not surprised by this.  Pubstats still shows the games above high and normal though, but I assume this is old cached data.

Answer (score -1):

go to dota buff then go click on the website then sign in through steam. after that it will show you the win rate you have plus your matchmaking so then you can know what is your matchmaking rating.

Answer (score -1):

Go to [DOTABUFF](http://www.dotabuff.com/) and type in your nickname, you will see your skill bracket under recent games info.